# How can I generate a large identity matrix in python without running into "memory full"?

Tags: python, numpy

I am using the code below:

```
n = 40000
numpy.matlib.identity(n)
```

Comment: This is probably not possible given your system resources.

Comment: What is this big identity matrix used for? Chances are you can use a less memory intensive option...

Comment: This was for a machine learning project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with scipy using [sparse matrix representation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.identity.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import identity
n = 30000
a = np.identity(n)
print a.nbytes
b = identity(n)
print b.data.nbytes
```

The difference is huge (quadratic): `7200000000` vs `240000`.

You can also try to decrease the size by providing appropriate [dtype](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html), like `a = np.identity(n, dtype='int8')` but this will only reduce the size linearly (with maximum linear factor of less than 200).

The same way you can do `b = identity(n, dtype='int8', format='dia')` which will reduce the size even further to `30000`.

**But the most important thing** is what are you planning to do with this matrix (highly doubt you just want to create it)? And some of the operations would not support sparse indices. Then you either have to buy more memory or come up with smart linear-algebra stuff to operate on parts of the matrices, store results on disk and merge them together.

Comment: Thanks Salvador Dali